# How GPUs could be utilized after network switch to Casper?

Tags: mining, proof-of-stake, gpu

Now Ethereum hashrate is ~550 Gh/s. That is approximately 22 thousand very powerful Radeon 290x GPUs. After network switch to PoS this hashpower could be used to mine science through Gridcoin. Or probably more interesting applications will emerge. It seems that there is huge [demand for GPU computation](https://medium.com/boost-vc/vr-and-cloud-graphics-dc4a970a815#.oz0mexp6g) from emerging VR industry. Do you have ideas how that opportunity could be used and what implementation already exist today?

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to like this answer, but there are several ways you can continue to use your GPUs:

1. You can play video games;
2. You can mine another coin which supports POW, including bitcoin (negative return), litecoin (negative return);
3. You can rent out your hashing power on sites like [nicehash](https://www.nicehash.com/)
4. You can run it at full power to warm you up in the winter;
5. You could surf websites;
6. You could watch movies;
7. You can edit movies;
8. You can contribute to ethereum.stackexchange;
9. You can use them to train machine learning models;
10. You can make a sick multi-monitor setup;
11. You can render 3D models at breakneck speeds;
12. You can bruteforce password hashes;
13. You can generate rainbow tables so you don't have to bruteforce later;
14. You can make a public art sculpture;
15. You can mine your own blockchain to feel wealthy;
16. You can simulate conway's game of life on a massive scale;
17. You can overclock them to start a bonfire;
18. You can make pretty fractals;
19. You could use it to bogosort large lists;

Good luck!